# Why to install a baker and a accuser we need pass the VERSION

Tags: baker

I would like to understand why to install a baker and a accuser we need pass the VERSION like that :

```
PROTOCOL="ptmumbai"
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-baker-$PROTOCOL
sudo apt-get install -y tezos-accuser-$PROTOCOL
```

Why we don't just have tezos-baker and tezos-accuser updated like any other software :

`apt update && apt upgrade`

It's a bit annoying to have to install each new version and change it into my Unit Files :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, with protocol-specific binaries, it would not make sense to have for instance tezos-baker be without the protocol in its name, because in case of an upgrade, your tezos-baker would stop working if you don't do it exactly at the moment where the protocol is changed on chain.

However, it would make sense to have software that can handle several protocols at once (instead of only one). In such case, we could avoid having to use single-protocol binaries. We could imagine having binaries that may handle 2 or 3 protocols at once. They'd be much heavier though.

We could also imagine having a script (in a meta package) that would be able to launch the right protocol-specific binary...

Anyways, I would **guess** that something is already on the roadmap but hasn't been prioritized.